# How to exit "SurfaceDrawing" mode?

Tags: edit-mode

I somehow got into this mode:

[image]

And I can't get back to normal Edit Mode anymore. Evey I switched to Edit Mode, the options on the header are something like "Stroke Selection Mode" instead of Vertex/Edge/Face. I don't even know what this mode is called or what it is for.

Comment: What is shown here is edit mode for a grease pencil object. So you're in edit mode...